# C# Dto constructor and dependency injection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I would like to know what is the best practice in designing the constructors of DTO objects.

say i have a Dto object like this:

```
class CustomerDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

There are several ways to construct the object:

I could declare a constructor:

```
public CustomerDto(string name, string surname, string phone, ...)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Surname = surname;
    this.Phone = phone;
    ...
}
```

When you see this constructor and immediately conclude a SRP (Single responsibility) violation?

Even though these attributes are all related.

One could also argue there is no need to validate the properties as this is a DTO and has NO behavior, and the behavior should rather be on the domain object that this maps from.

In C# we can also more elegantly construct this object:

```
var dto = new CustomerDto ()
{
    Name = "Some name",
    Surname = "Some surname"
}
```

Or use a fluent builder or a framework such as NBuilder.

There is also the usage of Auto mapping frameworks like Automapper. The problem is also using an Ioc container the ctor becomes complex, as well as the risk in swapping arguments for example, you pass in name where surname is or vice versa, the validation could miss this more easy then explicit mapping as above.

Please help convince me which is the better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency Injection - use with Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297322/dependency-injection-use-with-data-transfer-objects-dtos)

Comment: I came across this same problem, and decided against the constructor.. For a simple reason: later, in a month, or 6 months, myself or someone else is going to look at this and have to think about it the same way myself (and yourself) are thinking now. I've found thinking while reading code is an indication that it's too complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Value types as in your examples aren't dependencies. A dependency provides a functionality (or configuration) to the consumer. In your case they are just normal values that are assigned to your DTO. As long as the data belongs together you do not violate SRP even if you assign a lot of values in the constructor. The single responsibility in this case is to hold the data.

Also DTO's shouldn't be created by a IoC container and have no real dependencies. You should create them manually, by your persistency framework or using auto mapping.

If assigning the values using a constructor or properties is better depends on the usage. If they are required the constructor variant is better. If they are optional the property way is better.

Comment: What I like about this answer is it confirms what I though about a dependency and that these arent really dependencies they are not external sub systems that you want an Ioc container to substitute. Also the reason for option 2 is that it really allows the Auto mapping framework to do its thing it simply carries the data between boundaries. I did feel that the concern of the dto requiring say a name argument is not something it is really concerned about? agree?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using immutable data structures so DTO entity would not expose any setters, obviously in this way constructor should provide ability to initialize all underlying properties of a given DTO.

So I prefer:

```
public CustomerDto(string name, string surname, string phone, ...)
```

DTO is a Data Transfer Object, especially to represent a set of properties to be passed across a system (distributed as well) boundaries, so do not bother too much regarding [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation.
This is like Facade design pattern, it abstarcts a set of operations/services to simplify usage. So in this kase [Keep It Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) won.

Comment: What i am wondering about is Martin fowler describes the data trasnfer object as an object that holds state and no behavior and actually desribes it as a way to reduce method calls. By introducing constructor arguments and validating them you are adding behavior. Bear in mind that the purpose is to map from the domain to the view and validation happens most likely on the domain object. So do the dto really need to worry about the arguments and what is required as it is simply carrying the data somewhere else and validation is a different concern ?

Comment: Argument validation like `not null` / `not empty` is not an object behaviour, consider it like your application framework service stuff. But if you are going to encapsulate validation like `if ( customerRole == Roles.Vip) IncreaseBonus(x)` - this would be behaviour indeed and should not be in the DTO itself, DTO represents FINAL satte of an object

Comment: I just tested and it looks like Automapper is REALLY clever, it will map up the constructor argument names to the properties. The thing is though i does seem to me that it depends on usage, if you map from a domain object (already validated) to a view (which validates) there is no reason to create the constructor arguments, it looks like the constructor approach has no downsides, but i can see one big one. You cant immediately spot if an argument is the wrong way round, or in fact what property an argument maps to ?