# How to understand the rule: "Store in IoC container only services. Do not store any entities."

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

The rule "Store in IoC container only services. Do not store any entities." I've found in that [blog](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection.aspx) and it have a lot of supporters.

There are also sample of the class constructor:

```
    MyClass(ILog log, 
            IAudit audit, 
            IPermissions permissions, 
            IApplicationSettings settings) {/*..*/}
```

where MyClass was announced as entity that should not be stored in the container.

So "IoC ready service" can't depend on infrastructure .. services.

But now I completely do not understand how "IoC people" work with "real code". Service in C# still will be developed as a class, and that class usually depends on class that encapsulate logging, rarely depends on the class that encapsulate custom exception handling (e.g. converting unhandled Exception to FaultContract) etc. ...

I see some ways:
May be they just do not declare those infrastructure dependencies? Use them as functionality available form static methods?

Or may be "IoC supporters" think that "IoC ready" service should publish log/trace/authenticate/handleException  events as a part of service contract (and then yes - - there are no "dependencies on infrastructure")? But also that means that such service should be duplex (to post log events)...

May be theirs "services" are only proxies? Proxy do not have dependencies on infrastructure because of all infrastructure is remote, but I'm not happy to found that IoC container should be used to store only proxies. Am I right in my disappointment? But then what about MS Enterprise Library that is designed to sore loggers and handlers in the Unity container?

APPEND:

I understand it that way: there are services (with contracts), there are entities (business), and there are infrastructure stuff LogWriter, AuthenticationProvider;- creating/hosting service I initiate it with some infrastructure stuff (so I am publishing dependencies on infrastructure not on entities). What I still do not understand am I right in that or not?

APPEND 2:

After discussion I understand situation that way. ILog, etc - are services (even if they are infrastructure services) and therefore if the "MyClass" is the realization of the some service then rule is not violated. That means rule is good but sample is bad.

One problem left: I still do not understand the opposition of entities and services in one sentence without explanation. They are from different conceptual layers: 1) services-messages; and 2)business rules-entities.. So possibly first I should adopt new terminolgy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-object/4836790#4836790

Comment: Thank you for the link. There situation is much more clear for me: now I'm sure of course IoC is about infrastructure building, not about business entities building. And also want to add that in the rule "store only services; do not store any entities" there are opposition between services and entities, which is wrong by didactic reasons.

Comment: If you adopt the terminology put forth in *Domain-Driven Design*, Services and Entities are two entirely different things. I see nothing wrong with that. Of course, both are still Objects... :)

Comment: Ok. I got it, my problem was that I do not feel context. For me "Services" are concept from SOA. There we have "Business Services" from DDD.

Comment: Unfortunately, the word 'Service' is so horribly overloaded that it's almost meaningless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: entities should not depend on services! This is a huge part of the "inversion" part of dependency inversion. As stated in the post you linked to:

> I found the design of the question example is wrong in a sense that an entity (which MyClass is) should NOT have dependencies on infrastructure (or any other) services.

`MyClass`, in your example, depends on three cross-cutting concerns, plus `IApplicationSettings`. The cross-cutting concerns should be introduced using AOP/dynamic proxy techniques, or pubsub-style events if you prefer. And `MyClass` should be injected with settings specific to its functionality by whatever service is in charge of creating instances of it. For example, `PersonFactory` could be injected with `IApplicationSettings`, then create `Person` objects, passing `appSettings.SomePersonRelatedSetting` into the `Person` constructor.

Comment: I understand it that way there are services (with contracts), there are entities (business), and there are infrastructure stuff LogWriter, AuthenticationProvider - creating/hosting service i initiate it with some infrastructure stuff (publish dependencies on infrastructure). What I still do not understand am I right in that or not.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with application services depending on infrastructure services; I didn't see anything in the linked article arguing against that. It may still be cleaner and reduce your number of constructor parameters to use AOP/dynamic proxy/pubsub techniques, the former two of which are IoC container features anyway. But it's not as crucial as avoiding entity to service dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The rule "Store in IoC container only services. Do not store any entities." means that you should register in IoC container pair `interace` - `implementation`. This rule is a result of [dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). According to your example this means that you should extract public interface from your `MyClass` and use it instead of MyClass implementation.

Comment: I think you missed the point; `MyClass` is an entity, and so extracting an interface for DIP purposes is not necessary. (It might still be useful e.g. for mocking, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: @Domenic than infrastructure logic should be moved from `MyClass` into `MyClassService`, which actually should implement `IMyClassService` interface

Answer (score 0):

The rule that says

```
"Store in IoC container only services. Do not store any entities."
```

is talking from conceptual perspective and not from implementation perspective. Conceptually, entity represents data (or state) and perhaps data related rules (as methods). Service represents functionality exposed via published contract and generally, state-full services is not a good idea. So although C# `class` construct would be used to represent both service implementation and entity implementation - what this rule is saying is that only services should be put into IoC. IoC really acts as a configurable super-flexible factory that provides correct service implementation for the required service contract. Again, one can have pattern such as `ActiveRecord` where perhaps data and persistence functionality are merged - I as such don't like the pattern but there are many followers and typical usage would put such entities into IoC container. However, important difference would be probably the entity would be registered against some contract (and not implementation)

Again note that your code has dependencies on service contracts and not on specific service implementation. Now, dependencies can be exposed and resolved in multiple ways. You can mark dependencies by putting them as constructor parameters OR as public property getter/setter OR using declarative syntax such as attributes. These are typically resolved automatically by DI framework. However, you can always get/resolve some service by making explicit call such as `ILog log = DIContainer.Get<ILog>();`. So as far as Infrastructure services goes, I think that what the blog author is saying is that don't mark infrastructure services as explicit dependencies (by constructor args or properties etc). You can resolve them using code (as quoted above) or perhaps using simple singleton helpers etc. In a way, he is right because one can always assumes that every service/class depends on infrastructure and so dependencies need not be stated using public API.

Comment: Good example with the active record pattern. It is very non-IoC compliant, because you end up with an entity (e.g. `Person`) depending on a service (e.g. `IPersistenceService`). If you wish to fully embrace IoC, your entities should not depend on services active record-style.

Comment: Sorry, may be I still asking wrong question, but .. according this rule, could  service realization publish it dependencies on infrastructure stuff such LogWriter, AuhtenticationProvider? this stuff is not entity-related, at least in the service conceptual layer. possibly i could agree, publishing dependencies on infrastructure have a little common  with dependency injection principle. but i publish them because such dependencies exist and something should resolve them.. why not IoC container?