# DDD: is it ok to inject a Repository into an Entity?

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, repository, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not use an IoC container to resolve dependencies for entities/business objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec)

I asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475108/ddd-is-it-ok-to-inject-a-service-into-an-entity) in the past. However, I believe this is not a self-duplicate: the (good) answer to my original question was very specific to this domain problem, and does not discuss the problem in general.

Let's take a new example I came accross:

- I have a `Zone` entity, with an associated boundary;
- I have a `Store` entity, which has a `location` as well as a `zone` property;
- A `ZoneRepository` can find which `Zone` contains a specific location.

The `zone` property of the `Store` should never be set directly, but instead deducted from the `location` when this property is assigned. Therefore, it sounds logical to me to do this:

```java
class Store
{
    public void setLocation(Point location, ZoneRepository repo)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.zone = repo.findByLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Are there drawbacks, caveats to this approach? If so, can you suggest realistic alternatives?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. This question is about DDD perspective and the supposed duplicated question has nothing to do with DDD

Comment: @fabien7474 Welcome to StackOverflow, where a vote breeds another. You can vote to reopen this question if you think it's worth it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the relationship between Zone and Location? Zone must have a Location property, correct? Or otherwise you wouldn't be able to search zone by location. Could this be a bi-directional relationship? What I'm getting at, is why can't you do this?

```php
class Store
{
    public function setLocation(Point $location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->zone = $location->zone;
    }
}
```

alternatively, you cold use the repository in the layer above, and then just pass in what you need:

```php
class Store
{
    public function setLocation(Point $location, Zone $zone)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->zone = $zone;
    }
}
```

Generally, I would not inject the repository in unless absolutely necessary, and in this situation it is not. Even then, I would not pass it into the method, I would pass it in using an IOC container.

Comment: It's probably unclear in the question, but location is a `Point`, and the boundary of the Zone is a `Polygon`. When the Store's location is pinpointed on a map, I need to find which Zone contains that point.

Comment: In that case I would go for my second suggestion.

Comment: That's indeed a solution, but it doesn't offer a guarantee that this method will be called with consistent `location` <-> `zone` data!