# Getting a set of dependencies to a class deeply nested in the dependency graph

Tags: c#, java, oop, dependency-injection, dependencies

So here is my problem:

For instance, consider that:

A `File` has a set of `Classes`, as well as `Imports`.

A `Class` has a set of `Instance Methods`, `Static Methods` and `Variables`.

A `Instance Method` has `Parameters` and a `Body`.

The `Body` has ... yadayada.

The problem, when modelling this in a OO way is that `Body` may need a lot of specific dependencies to function:

```
class Body {
    ...

    public Body(Dependency1, Dependency2, Dependency_n, ...) { }

    ...
}
```

that all the other classes won't need, to run. The question I'm putting here is on how to get those dependencies to `Body` without having to pass all this dependencies through `File`, `Class` and `InstanceMethod`.

I could create a `BodyFactory`, but the problem would still be the same, as I'd have to pass the `BodyFactory` through `File`, `Class` and `InstanceMethod`, if I'm not missing anything.

How to solve this issue without resorting to singletons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `Body` implement an `IBody` interface and let `InstanceMethod` depend only on `IBody` and `IEnumerable<IParameter>` (if we assume C# - in Java it would be a differently named collection interface, but the principle would be the same).

Repeat this process of [refactoring to Facade Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx) all the way to the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), where you can then [compose the entire object graph](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/ComposeObjectGraphsWithConfidence.aspx) like this:

```
File file = new File(
    new List<IClass>
    {
        new Class(
             new List<IInstanceMethod>
             {
                 new InstanceMethod(
                     new List<IParameter>(),
                     new Body(
                         new Dependency1()
                         new Dependency2(),
                         new DependencyN()))
             },
             new List<IStaticMethod>(),
             new List<IVariable>())
    },
    new List<IImport>());
```

Comment: The trouble is that I actually want to have all the instance generation logic to be inside Instance Method. From what it seems from your suggestion, one would want to pass the instantiation logic to the composition root. Am I right?

Comment: The trouble with "Compose object graphs with confidence" is that the number of objects that will be created at run-time is unknown.

Comment: I do get what you mean, but I cannot think of a way of doing what you're saying when there are an arbitrary number of File instances, Class instances, Instace Methods instances and Body instances. At least not without putting all the Body instance creation logic currently found on InstanceMethod outside of all this dependency graph.

Comment: If there are unknown numbers of instances it sounds like you looking towards composing Entities or Value objects, and not Services. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec/4836790#4836790

Comment: I'm going to read the paper. Anyway, I think what I want to do here is to separate the logic and data (in a kind of functional style - or better yet, how one does with compiler's symbols table).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are dreaming about kind of injection framework. For example [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as Java is concerned, I don't think you have a workaround here, if a method takes n parameters, then you are going to have to pass them, so you are going to have to carry them all the way, a solution to make this more elegant is to create a DataWrapper, call it BodyBean and pass it also all the way down.

Then you have the other option don't use parameters, then if these guys are singletons, just inject them, which by the way is the option I would recommend you