# Persistent objects and Dependancy Injection

Tags: dependency-injection

Are there any scenarios where my POCOs should participate in DI. Is that a code smell ?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not use an IoC container to resolve dependencies for entities/business objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec)

Answer (score 1):

I think of a code smell as an indication that something may be wrong, but isn't necessarily wrong.  I don't know that this rises to that level.

Imagine that you had a Customer POCO and a short-lived CustomerValidator object that operated on a single customer.  I use xtor injection for what I think of as critical dependencies, and the CustomerValidator certainly takes a critical dependency on a Customer -- it makes no sense without it.

So, in my estimation, that's a scenario (albeit sort of a contrived one) where this is fine.  I would say it has to do more with the lifetime of your object as compared to the POCO as well as how critically your object depends on the POCO.

To be clear, though, this isn't necessarily a common case for me when I code. I just don't know that I'd term it a 'smell'.  Perhaps if it's happening a lot...  my two cents, anyway.

Edit:  for instance:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Ssn { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerValidator
{
    private readonly Customer _customer;

    public CustomerValidator(Customer customer)
    {
        _customer = customer;
    }

    public void FixIfNotValid()
    {
        if (!IsValid())
        {
            _customer.Ssn = "123456789";
            _customer.LastName = "Smith";
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_customer.Ssn) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_customer.LastName);
    }
}
```

Here, you have a POCO (Customer) and a validator object that has a one per POCO relationship with the POCO.  That is, the validator encapsulates the POCO as part of its state and performs some (admittedly contrived) operations on it.

Without the POCO, the validator object makes no sense, so it stands to reason that you'd write your code in such a way as to force clients to supply the POCO (i.e. constructor dependency injection).  Ignoring the contrived nature of this example, I wouldn't consider this to be a code smell.

You have a dependency and you're injecting it here.  If later, you define inheritors of 
Customer, the validator will still work on them.  You can test your validator by substituting in a test double of your POCO.  So, the various motivations for DI apply in this case as they do in cases of injecting service-oriented classes.  So, personally, I see no reason not to inject.

Comment: When you say POCO, is the "C" referring to C#?