# Entity Framework and constructor injection with lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Is there a way to implement dependency injection with Entity framework and lazy loading?

I am aware of method when you are hooking to `ObjectStateManagerChanged`, but I'd like to use constructor injection instead, and keep my model entities unaware of any IOC containers. (Lets say I have separated BLL and DAL and want to keep my BLL with least external dependencies possible).

Thank you.

Comment: Prevent from using dependency injection in your entities altogether. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec

Comment: I'd agree... but I need to implement configurable security context. Simple example: I'd like to manage access level to model (read/write permissions to certain entitytypes/properties) from external app.

Comment: Try using the [command / handler pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for writing business operations. By defining one generic interface, you have great extensibility and the power to implement security checks by implementing a simple decorator.

Comment: Thank you. And that is what I am doing for business operations, but with lazy loading, ui developer can go unrestricted to any entity in relational tree. And I need to manage access to properties also.

Comment: You can prevent lazy loading and return DTOs. This way you as a BL developer have control over what is returned to the PL and there will be no surprises.

Comment: @Steven, post something as your answer, even if it was not exactly what I was looking though, thank you for all your input. They backed my conjectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent from using dependency injection in your entities altogether. Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec) for instance.

Try using the [command / handler pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for writing business operations. By defining one generic interface, you have great extensibility and the power to implement security checks by implementing a simple decorator.

To prevent UI developers from accessing data they shouldn't be accessing, write one (or multiple) decorators that wrap command handlers (and [query handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)) and prevent from returning entities with lazy loading abilities from your business layer. Instead return [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s. This way the business layer has full control.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use constructor injection with EF. EF always use default constructor when materializing entity from database records. The only option you have in this case is using `ObjectMaterialized` event of `ObjectContext` and use properties in your entity to pass your initialization data.

You should follow @Steven's comments to implement logic you need.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and advices, They were considered already. Question was on particular combination of technologies - Lazy EF + DI. Anyway I got my answers, even if they are negative. Thank you again.