# SOLID: Same-class constructor call allowed?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

An important property of really SOLID code is the fact that constructor calls do not often happen within the actual application code but primarily in the composition root and factory methods where necessary.
This makes a lot of sense to me, and I adhere to this wherever I can.

I have created a simple class where it seems to me it is not only allowed, but actually correct to deviate from the above rule.
This abstracts some simple Registry queries to facilitate unit testing of some other code:

```
public class RegistryKeyProxy : IRegistryKey
{
    private RegistryKey registrykey;

    public RegistryKeyProxy(RegistryKey registrykey)
    {
        this.registrykey = registrykey;
    }

    public IRegistryKey OpenSubKey(string subKeyName)
    {
        var subkey = this.registrykey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);

        return (null == subkey ? null : new RegistryKeyProxy(subkey));
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSubKeyNames()
    {
        return this.registrykey.GetSubKeyNames();
    }

    public object GetValue(string valueName)
    {
        return this.registrykey.GetValue(valueName);
    }
}
```

The `OpenSubKey()` method actually creates an instance of this same class without using a factory, but because of the closed concept that the Registry presents, it actually seems desirable to me not to return *anything* that looks like a Registry key, but really something that works exactly the same way as the current object.

I know that in the end it's up to me just how SOLID I want to work, but I'd like to know if this generally is a feasible path to go because of the nature of the underlying concept, or if this is not an exception to the rule but actually a SOLID violation.

Comment: "One of the most important properties of really SOLID code is the fact that constructors (save for basic framework classes that can't be replaced anyway without breaking the code's function) are never called within the actual application code" - citation needed.

Comment: A class calling its own constructor is a private implementation detail and it's perfectly reasonable for code within a class to be tightly coupled in its private implementation details.  There is no new dependency being introduced here.

Comment: @DonRoby: I admit the wording is a bit too absolute, but from my understanding that is one of the main things that make SOLID work. I also remember reading something pretty close to that from Mark Seemann the other day (though I don't remember where).

Comment: IMO that principle only applies to Services and similar constructions. And not to ValueObjects, Entities,...

Comment: I guess I really went a bit overboard there, going with too strict an interpretation of DIP. And after thinking about it again, that Seemann post was not about constructors but a DI container; so it was related to constructors but sufficiently different. I'll modify my question to make that initial statement more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about the [Dependency Inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). This principle doesn't say that you should never new up objects at all, but it differentiates between two types of objects. Objects that implement behavior (services), and objects that contain data (DTOs, Value Types, Entities).

It would be rather silly in not newing up DTOs, since there is no behavior to be abstracted. They just contain data. (Just as would be silly to add an `IPerson` interface to a `Person` DTO).

Miško Hevery calls them [injectables and newables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/), which is an nice terminolgoy.

For more information, see this Stackoverflow question: [Why not use an IoC container to resolve dependencies for entities/business objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046)

Comment: Thanks for this concise clarification; that makes perfect sense. Injectables and newables are indeed an accessible approach of thinking about it.