# How would I configure ninject to use the base factory for all derived types of that class?

Tags: c#, ninject

Given a base class in which we are supposed to use static factory methods to construct all derived classes, how would I bind such that derived types are created by the base factory?

```
 public abstract class BusinessObject<T> where T : BusinessObject<T>, new()
    {
        #region Member Variables

        /// <summary>
        /// Object that acts as a lock when retrieving or creating the singleton instance.
        /// </summary>
        private static object singletonLock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton instance of this business object with default connection string.
        /// </summary>
        private static T instance;

        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        #endregion Member Variables

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the connection string.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The connection string.</value>
        public virtual string ConnectionString { get; protected set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default connection string for business object.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual string DefaultConnectionString { get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlConnection"].ConnectionString; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates or retrieves the singleton instance of this business object.
        /// </summary>
        public static T Instance { get { return GetInstance(); } }

        protected static log4net.ILog Log { get { return log; } }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BusinessObject"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        protected BusinessObject()
        {
            ConnectionString = DefaultConnectionString;
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns singleton business object using default connection string.
        /// </summary>
        public static T GetInstance()
        {
            if (instance != null)
                return instance;

            // If instance has not been created, create new instance (with thread-safe lock).
            lock (singletonLock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new T();
            }

            return instance;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns new instance of business object using custom connection string.
        /// </summary>
        public static T GetInstance(string connectionString)
        {
            return new T() { ConnectionString = connectionString };
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
```

Sample snippet of derived class:

```
public class ProjectBO : BusinessObject<ProjectBO>
{

    #region Constructors

    [Obsolete("Use instance property instead", false)]
    public ProjectBO() { }

    static ProjectBO()
    {
        quotaGroupBlacklist = new List<int>();
        unavailableQuotaGroupsByMember = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        unavailableProjectsByMember = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    }

    #endregion Constructors
}
```

so I want to (by convention) hook up all derived types to use the base class factory method `GetInstance(string)`

how can I do this without changing the base or derived classes?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec

Comment: yeah I don't like this domain object setup either, but it's not mine to change.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do that:

```
this.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(BusinessObject<>))
    .BindWith<BusinessObjectBindingGenerator>());

public class BusinessObjectBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        yield return bindingRoot
            .Bind(type)
            .ToMethod(ctx => CreateBusinessObject(type));
    }

    private static object CreateBusinessObject(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(BusinessObject<>)
            .MakeGenericType(type)
            .GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: i didn't test the reflection stuff but i think it's correct.

Also note that i think it's bad design. I think it's a bit smelly.

Why are you even using the `.GetInstance` method? You could just as easily replace it with:

```
this.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(BusinessObject<>))
    .BindToSelf()
    .Configure(x => x.InSingletonScope()));
```

Comment: I don't like the design of the library I'm consuming, but don't have control over it. I suppose going at it the way you are suggesting won't warn of the `[Obsolete]` attribute declared in all derived classes at compile time (hopefully not giving them another reason not like my work around). However, none of these account for wanting to either use the GetInstance overload with a connection string, setting it via property injection, or using a `.WhenActivated` not that those adjustments look difficult to the given code. but maybe it drives towards a more full understanding of what I'm doing?