# Make Entity Framework work with object interface and Ninject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

i have object with interface defined in my Domain layer:

```
public MyClass: IMyClass
{
    public int id {get;set;}
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

now iam trying to use interface in context but don't find any way:

```
public DbSet<IMyClass> MyClasses{ get; set; }
```

don't work when EF try to create db

i setup a ninject module (BindDLModule) with

```
Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>();
```

and create a kernel in context

```
IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new BindDLModule());
```

but don't know how to use _kernel in DbSet configuration to get type of the mapped implementation

EDIT 1

An example to illustrate mocking entities for testing:

```
public Class1
{
    ...
    public Class1(){...}

    public Class2 class2Property {get;}

    public void setClass2 (Class2 class2Value)
    {
    //logic here
    }
}

public Class2
{
//Simple class with construcor and few properties
}
```

in test i would write

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1(Mock.Of<Class2>())
```

in this way Class2 constructor will not be called and test remain atomic on Class1.

EDIT 2

Using Interface is not mandatory, i simply want to fake some domain entities
Or, in other words, with interface all works well, only EF give me some problems so i rethink the use of interface, but at this point need other way to unit test entities.

Comment: Why are your trying to hide your domain entity behind an abstraction?

Comment: Starting with DDD i have put many methods with logic in my domain object and create factory for creation so decided to use interface-implementation pattern

Comment: Even with DDD, it's quite ununusual to hide entities behind an abstraction. Entities are the absolute core of your application; they should not need abstracting.

Comment: You might also be interested in this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835046/why-not-use-an-ioc-container-to-resolve-dependencies-for-entities-business-objec

Comment: now iam reading http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/05/09/entity-interface-anti-pattern/. Interesting point of view. But without interface, entity can be mocked? in test if a class1 has a class2 property i would like to test class1 constructor without a call to class2 constructor

Comment: IMO Your entity should never be mocked.

Comment: and how can test a single object in an atomic test? Now i do "myClass1Object.MyCLass2Property = Mock.Of<IMyClass2>()", in this way MyClass2 constructor is not called. One more thing: now i add code contract to object interface because I read that the contracts are better on interfaces

Comment: Code contracts is a different question (which I can't answer. Post a new question here on SO). Entities are called from commands and their dependencies are passed into their methods from the command. You can test the command and you can test the entity methods in isolation.

Comment: Events have also constructor and method that imo have to be tested

Comment: @Steven: why should entities not be mocked? I think it warrants thorough explanation when one recommends to deviate from the "standard path" (TDD/having an interface for every class so you can test classes in isolation). Why are the normal arguments for test isolation not applicable? I would agree that http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/05/09/entity-interface-anti-pattern/ answers these questions.

Comment: @gt.guybrush how about you post an example of an entity implementation where Mocking is warranted (basically a method more complicated than get / set).

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual DbSet<_kernel.Get<IClass1>().GetType())> Classes1{ get; set; }
```

can be solution if i find the correct sintax to write it