# Injecting service into domain object once again

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I've got specific domain that operates on a geographical data. I'm implementing this project in TypeScript and NodeJS and have following classes:

- **Point** - value object containing latitude and longitude
- **Area** - value object containing set of points as a shape definition
- **Sector** - entity (it's not persisted, but it's mutable) - containing area and set of points that lie inside it

Now I need implement a method named `isPointInside(point: Point)` that calculates whether provided point fits inside of area or not. I don't want to implement it by myself, because out there are libraries that will do it for me. Right now I've decided to use that one: https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib .

Also I'm using IoC framework for TypeScript called inversifyjs, nothing fancy - provides DI through annotations.

So I created an interface called "GeoService" that provides methods responible for geographical calculations, and I intend to use it rather heavily in that domain model. Using inversify I provided GeoLib adapter that implements my interface and I'd really like to use it somehow from inside my Area class.

So that's first problem, but it's not the end of my struggles :-).

I've got another class, called **SectorGrid**, that contains grid of sectors (every sector is the square in this usecase) in two-dimensional data structure. SectorGrid has a method `addPoint(point: Point)`. Responsibility of that method is to find a sector that provided point fits in, and if it doesn't find one, to create it. Now it not only needs GeoService to calculate where initial point of the sector should be (distance from grid center), but also it needs to create Sector - and there I faced the issue while I was writing tests, there was too much logic and I've decided to provide some kind of a sector factory to SectorGrid not only to simplify tests, but also to encapsulate sector creation logic (that's quite complex). So another service to inject now, and no idea how to do it in a way that won't lead me to problems.

For now I just injected those two services as static properties of these classes, but that's not something I'm proud of and I'm looking for other options.

I know that my design may be be overcomplicated and I'm looking for a way to simplify it, but I don't want to end in the Anemic Domain Models land. Having something like Area object and not being able to put geographical calculations inside of it sounds exactly like anemic model for me.

Also I've read quite a few discussions about injecting services into entities, but none of them satisfied me as they either provided to conclusion like "don't do this" or "just do this and don't bother", or provided solutions like domain event that totally doesn't fit in my case.

Comment: Why don't you inject the functions (callback style) ?

and you only give the symptoms without code, so we don't really know what your service do and why it's overcomplicated

Comment: Honestly I don't think that the code would make anything more clear than it's now - it's too much code (calculating sector position is complex) and also I'm still discovering my domain, so some of those classes contain too many responsibilities and you might not see what's what.

How injecting a callback function would make it better than just injecting an object that calculates all the things in descriptive way? Also I need not only single operation, but few of them (bearing, distance, point-in-area, destination point calculation based on bearing and distance etc...).

Comment: If all the complex logic actually happens in infrastructure components you do not really need a domain model at all. Being anemic is only bad when you claim to implement a domain model, but a functionnal approach can be just as efficient if it's the right one. If you need an external service for each method call and the only thing the aggregate does is delegate the logic to that service entirely then your model is still anemic, it's just not assuming it's anemia and hides it.

Comment: In fact there's no complex logic in the infrastructure. I'm relying on it just for geospatial calculations. Those calculations are complex only from mathematical point of view, there's no business logic in them. Regarding factory that I mentioned - it's a part of the domain, but it's a convenient way to encapsulate complex logic that entity is not quite responsible for.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit my comment  anymore, so I'll post another one. The project that I'm working on is an augmented reality game like Ingress or Pokémon Go, believe me, there's enough business logic in that to create a really complex domain model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of handling cases where domain objects needs to collaborate with services is to inject these services at the method level and apply the ISP principle to ensure the dependencies are not wider than needed.

E.g. `addPoint(point: Point, geoService: GeoService)`

Another common way of dealing with the problem is to resolve the dependency from the application service and pass the result into the aggregate method, but when that approach is leaking too much logic inside the application layer you should probably use service injection at the method level instead.

> but could you elaborate a little more about the latter solution

Well imagine that a `Project` aggregate must adjust it's completion status and percentage based on it's linked `Task`s aggregates in an eventually consistent manner. To do so the `Project` must find out how many tasks are completed so far.

Rather than passing in a `TaskRepository`/`TaskCompletionSummaryProvider` into the `Project.adjustCompletionState` method you could resolve the dependency at the application layer level.

```
var project = projectRepository.projectOfId(someProjectId);
var taskCompletionSummary = taskRepository.taskCompletionSummaryOfProject(project.id());
project.adjustCompletionState(taskCompletionSummary);


class Project {
    public void adjustCompletionState(TaskCompletionSummary summary) {
        //The following line could be seen as defensive programming. You could also trust that the application layer is doing it's job correctly. It wouldn't be required at all if a `TaskCompletionSummaryProvider` service would be injected directly instead.
        if (this.id != summary.projectId()) throw new InvalidOperationException('Wrong summary for project');

        if (summary.allCompleted()) this.completionState = ProjectCompletionState.COMPLETED;
        else this.completionState = ProjectCompletionState.inProgress(summary.completionPercentage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that most helpful answer till now, but could you elaborate a little more about the latter soultion?

Comment: Thanks once more, I hate it that there's no clean way to encapsulate additional dependencies in the domain layer, even if domain depends on them just by design, but I also see the reason not to do this, so I think I'll just have to live with that and adapt my design :)

Comment: @Mikz Well in most domains the domain model doesn't constantly need to use external domain services so it may be less painful.