# DDD: is accessing repository from aggregate root considered bad practice?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

I've read that accessing repository from aggregate root considered bad practice.
If it is, than consider following example:

```
class User {
   private String username;
   public void changeUsername(String newUsrname) {
     // How will I persist username to database if I don't have access to repository from aggregate root?
     ...
   }
}
```

**How will I persist username to database if I don't have access to repository 
from aggregate root?**

I see it like this:

```
class User {
    private String username;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public User(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void changeUserName(String newUsername) {
       this.username = newUserName;
       userRepository.save(this); 
    }
}
```

Or I've missed something in DDD concepts?

Comment: your example shows ActiveRecord not DDD.

Comment: @dit, how would you achieve this in DDD way?

Comment: check this DDD-example: https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core

Comment: @dit, From example you provided, I should introduce UserService, in that userService I should have UserService.changeUserName(userId, username) which will get user from repository, call user.changeUsername and service will store user back... So interaction with domain should be don through services? And what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Repository has methods like `getById`, `update(user)`, `delete(user)` and implements no logic, just CRUD operations. The logic will be implemented in a Service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok for entities to access repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827670/is-it-ok-for-entities-to-access-repositories)

Answer (score 7):

> How will I persist username to database if I don't have access to repository from aggregate root?

Current practices normally handle I/O in the application component, rather than in the domain model.

```
Application {
    void when(ChangeUserName command) {
        User user = this.userRepository.getUserById(command.userId);
        user.changeName(command.name);
        this.userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Recommended reading: [Vladimir Khorikov](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/10/05/how-to-know-if-your-domain-model-is-properly-isolated/) on domain model isolation.

Comment: It's Vlad Khononov, I'm reading his book right at this moment :P

Comment: Vlad Khononov (author of _Learning Domain Driven Design_) and Vladimir Khorikov  (author of Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns) are different people.

Comment: This is a nice example. I have one question, why would I do this when I can have one method (e.g `updateUserName(newName string)`) in my repository which updated the DB directly using SQL and then I won't have to pull out the User object from the DB?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Because there's a thing called "always-valid state"  in DDD, to keep the data in memory/variable always up-to-date. The `updateUserName` function you mentioned is more like "Data Driven" instead of "Domain Driven".

Comment: @YamiOdymel How updating a field in the DB can cause an invalid state?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Because you should thinking about "operating the object" instead of "interacting with database". You may also forget to update the local variable if you called `userRepository.updateUserName` directly, and since Aggregate Root is the Domain Object, you should call Aggregate Root to update the field, then call Repository to save the whole, so the data on both sides will be synced/valid. Also if you called `userRepository.updateUserName` in Application Service might causes the domain logic leak to Application Service.

Comment: @YamiOdymel this is very counterintuitive. If I want an `API` endpoint for updating the user name then I should take the entire object out of the database and then update the name and then insert the entire object back into the database?

Comment: You are running into one of two areas of confusion: (a) domain models are too big a hammer to use when we are "just" saving a copy of information that belongs to someone else and (b) when we do need sophisticated domain modeling around a concept like "user name", the entity that we are taking out of the database is going to be only the information that our modeling needs, not the entire kitchen sink of a "user".

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Your example is true for DDD. That's why there are alot question like "_Should we load entire Aggregate Root?_" or "_Lazy-loading Aggregate root_" on StackOverflow. But I think it could be bad Aggregate Root modeling. Because an Aggregate Root is not 1:1 mapping to your Database Model, it's being modeled by how you will use the data (busniess logic).

Comment: @YamiOdymel I hear you but I feel like my initial question is still unanswered.  Why should I bother taking anything out of the database when I can just update it in the database?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Because DDD requires you to think with Aggregate Root. Operating Database in Application Service (AS) leaks the Domain to AS. You can call `updateUserName` internally in Repository, just don't expose them to AS.

Comment: It's better to stop thinking about how data will getting saved to database, it's not really Domain-Driven, and your Domain will be stuck by database implementation. Modeling Domain first, and think about database later. Surly there will be trade-off like performance if you pull entire Aggregate Root every time. So I suggest to use part of DDD and don't follow it mentally. But **stop thinking about database** is part of the key in DDD I think.

Comment: @YamiOdymel Got it. Thank you for taking the time to explain. Means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend a little the answer given by @VoiceOfUnreason (which is totally right) here a quick explanation on why injecting repositories via constructor to Aggregate Roots is not advisable:

The repository should depend on the object it returns, not the other way around. The reason for this is that your "domain object" (more on that later) can exist (and should be testable) without being loaded or saved (that is, having a dependency on a repository).

Basically your design says that in order to have an user, you need to provide a MySQL/Mongo/XXX instance connection which is an infrastructure detail. Your domain should not know anything about how it is persisted. Your domain knows about the behavior, invariants, business rules and so on.

These concepts just help you to create code easier to maintain as well as help you to apply best practices such as SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: In this case, domain will not now anything about infrastructure, because I'm passing just repository interface, and repository interface is a part of domain.

Comment: Just think about the unit test of the User class. Say that in order to change the name of the user you have some invariants like it cannot be empty, nor longer than a certain length, etc. Ensuring the invariants is what your User AR is responsible for, but if you also adds the responsibility of persisting, fetching and so, you are breaking SRP making harder the maintenance of the AR class plus the unit tests.